# Segmentation fault when called mosrcat() with 5 or above argment

Tags: c, linux, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
int mosrcat(char *o, int tsize, ...) {
  strong textregister int cot = 0;
  va_list ap;
  char *t;
  va_start(ap, tsize);
  t = va_arg(ap, char *);
  while(t != NULL) {
    while((*(o++) = *(t++)) != 0) {
    cot++;
    if(cot >= tsize) return -1;
    }
    t = va_arg(ap, char *);
   o--;
  }
va_end(ap);
return cot;
}

int main(void) {
  char *t1 = "/lib/modules/";
  char *t3 = "3.18.3-200.fc23.x86_64";
  char *t5 = "/lib/modules/";
  char *q = (char *)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
  mosrcat(q, 1000 ,t1, t3); //OK
  mosrcat(q, 1000 ,t1, t3, t5); //Segmentation fault
  printf("%s\n",q);
  return 0;
 }
```

When I called mosrcat() with 5 or above arguments, it crushed. But NO PROBLEM with 4 arguments. In mosrcat() function, char point 'o' appear "" after the second loop. This expression is

```
 while((*(o++) = *(t++)) != 0)
```

But 'o' always equal to "", not the value of 't'
How can I solve it?

-- Problem fixed --
Is that any problem?

Comment: You should test` malloc` return...

Comment: ...and you **have to** add `#include <stdlib.h>` for `malloc`.

Comment: You should re-work your code listing - Something is wrong with the first variable declarations around `strong textregister...`

Comment: Do not edit your question with the solution. It will  problematic for future viewer.

Comment: I am the beginner, then how should I do ? Should I change it back

Comment: No problem. I  already restored the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [man](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg) says for `va_arg` function

> If there is no next argument, or if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), random errors will occur.

The problem is that `va_arg` doesn't return `NULL` for the first not passed parameter.You should pass `NULL` as additional parameter to use your algorithm.

So

```
    mosrcat(q, 1000 ,t1, t3, NULL);
    mosrcat(q, 1000 ,t1, t3, t5, NULL);
```

Or, as shown into @FlorinPetriuc answer, you can pass number of variable arguments you are passing to `mosrcat` function.

Other stuff are:

1) add `#include <stdlib.h>` to support `malloc`.

2) always check the `malloc` return: it can fail.

```
if (q != NULL)
{
    mosrcat(q, 1000 ,t1, t3, NULL);
    mosrcat(q, 1000 ,t1, t3, t5, NULL);
    printf("%s\n",q);
}
```

3) Last thing memory `malloc`ated variable must be `free`d before program exits so

```
    ...
    free(q);
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Also, since you've added other stuff, he should free q after printf.

Comment: problem fixed, thank for your options. But I have one problem that why printf() don't need to add NULL as the last argument?

Comment: @JoeMa Because of it count arguments based on format specifier passed to it. I mean: if you use a format like `"%s %d\n"` `printf` check only 2 variable args, and some decent compiler too. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling va_arg until t becomes NULL.

You either add one NULL argument when you call mosrcat like this:

```
  mosrcat(q, 1000 ,t1, t3, NULL); //OK
  mosrcat(q, 1000 ,t1, t3, t5, NULL);
```

or you pass the number of arguments as a parameter and mosrcat becomes:

```
int mosrcat(char *o, int tsize, int n, ...) {
  strong textregister int cot = 0;
  va_list ap;
  char *t;
  va_start(ap, n);
  t = va_arg(ap, char *);
  while(n--) {
    while((*(o++) = *(t++)) != 0) {
    cot++;
    if(cot >= tsize) return -1;
    }
    t = va_arg(ap, char *);
   o--;
  }
va_end(ap);
return cot;
}
```